# Django object filtering with variables

Tags: python, django

I have  model that looks like this:

```
class Beacon(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    bid =  models.CharField()
    campaigns = models.ManyToMany(Campaign)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

In my api view, I am trying to find a specific Beacon given a bid (this is beacon id btw). So I have something that looks like this:

```
def SawBeacon(request, beacon_id):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        Beacon  = Beacon.objects.filter(bid__beacon_id=%s) % beacon_id
```

This doesn't work.. But I think you get the idea of what I am trying to do. I want to take the incoming beacon_id argument and filter down to a specific beacon that matches this ID.

1. How would I do this?
2. When I filter down an object,  do I get the object itself or will I get the value?

Comment: What about: Beacon.objects.filter(bid__beacon_id=(%s) % (beacon_id))?

Comment: Question: I actually don't know if the "bid__beacon_id" part is correct. More specifically the "beacon_id" part .I am just copying previous examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting one instance, you'll want to use get rather than filter. Try:

```
Beacon.objects.get(bid=beacon_id)
```

When you use filter, you'll return a queryset.

Comment: I think he's actually looking for `Beacon.objects.get(id=beacon_id)`

Comment: But isn't bid his field for beacon_id?

Comment: Correct. Filter returns a queryset, even if there's only one instance in the queryset.

Comment: Get will also throw an error if the object doesn't exist so you should always anticipate this with a try except statement. You can use django.core.exceptions ObjectDoesNotExist to check for this.